# Stop decreasing distance value of player when it moves in the opposite direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player that jumps when it hits a platform. Kind of like doodle jump. The score is based on the distance travelled in the y axis. The problem is, when the player jumps up, the distance value (score) increases but when the player lands back onto the platform, the distance value decreases and hence the score also decreases. I want to stop the score from decreasing. Here's the script :

```
public GameObject player;
float beginPos;
float curPos;
public int Multiplier;

void Start () {
     beginPos = player.transform.position.y;
}

 void Update () {
     curPos = player.transform.position.y - beginPos;
     int Distance = Mathf.RoundToInt(curPos * Multiplier);
     Debug.log(Distance);
 }
```

Comment: Guess you could add a property to the player that indicates if he is jumping or not, and if so, no deduction of the score?

Comment: Sounds like you may want an additional variable like apex and build your calculation around that.

Comment: The player is constantly jumping! There is no movement. He touches the platform and jumps up in the +y direction. He misses the platform, it's game over. Any other ideas? I tried making another variable,  maxDist that would store the distance and compare it with the previous value but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Have a variable for `lastPos` and only update `lastPos` and calculate the score if `curPos > lastPos`?

Comment: what should I equate lastPos to?

Comment: if i understand it correctly, the score would always go up, right? so why not simply check if the currently calculated score is higher than the one in previous frame. if so update, else discard it.

Comment: You're welcome. Dalton beat me to writing it into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a max height and only update score if you go past the max height reached.

```
float beginPos;
float curPos;
public int Multiplier;
float maxHeight;
 void Start () {
     beginPos = player.transform.position.y;
     maxHeight = beginPos;
}
void Update () {

    curPos = player.transform.position.y - beginPos;

     if(curPos > maxHeight)
     {
         int Distance = Mathf.RoundToInt(curPos* Multiplier);
         maxHeight = curPos;
         Debug.log(Distance);
     }
}
```

Comment: Cannot set a maxHeight as the player constantly moves up! It's postion keeps changing.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. In this case `maxHeight` is simply remembering the highest point the player has ever reached. If the current player position surpasses `maxHeight` then you know he's higher than he's been before so the score is updated and the `maxHeight` is set to the current position.

Comment: WORKED! WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! using another variable was the way to go. Thank You again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update () {
     curPos = player.transform.position.y - beginPos;
     if (curPos > 0) {
        distance = Mathf.RoundToInt(curPos * Multiplier);
     }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The value still decreases. For reference the player doesn't stay at (0,0,0). He constantly moves up.